# Error loading python27.dll (error code 14001) while running Jython script by cmd

Tags: java, cmd, environment-variables, jython-2.7

I have installed Jython on my Windows 7 machine, something I did often. 
I have set the environment variable `PATH` with the path `C:\jython2.7.1\bin\` and I launched the program from cmd as `jython myProgram.py`. 
The following error appears:

> Error loading Python DLL: C:\jython2.7.1\bin\python27.dll (error code 14001)

I've also tried to launch the program with `C:\jython2.7.1\jython.jar myProgram.py` and it works! The problem is that I can't debug at runtime.
Why that error while I run `jython myProgram.py`? It had never happened to me before. 
Yet the `python27.dll` file in the `bin` folder is there! 
I hope it's nothing serious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows 7 you are using a too high version of Jython. Go to this [site](https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.python%20AND%20a:jython-installer&core=gav), download and install the `2.7.0` version. 
After that, set the `PATH` environment variable as `C:\jython2.7.0\bin`.